# AngularJS with Wordpress route issue

Tags: ajax, wordpress, angularjs, routes

I've been playing with AngularJS for a few weeks and feeling like I'm learning a lot more about SPAs. Given that Angular is front-end and requires a third party data source to get stuff from a database I have used the WP JSON plugin and am now trying to make it work on my Wordpress site.

So far, I have done this which gets the posts and puts them into the template:

```
$http.get('http://site:8888/wp-json/posts')
.success(function(data, status, headers, config){
  $scope.items = data;
})
```

Great, works well. Now I want to link my posts to an individual post page, and I'm completely stuck as what to use for my templateUrl (if this is even needed):

```
.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
  $routeProvider
  .when('/:category/:post', {
    templateUrl: ?????
  });
}])
```

The conflict here is that WP already offers routing. But I need to almost sidestep it so I can get AngularJS working to do AJAX loads for me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a SPA you won't need wordpress routing at all. Wordpress will be just the dataprovider for your frontend. Your question really is not about using wordpress and angular but "How to use ngRoute?".

There's a great example on how Routes work in angulars developer guide: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route

To answer your question: `templateUrl` is a path to an Html file that contains the template for your post. Angular lazyloads that file using `$templateCache` and evaluates it. So you could initialize a Controller there that would get data from wordpress and so on.

Comment: Thanks Julian, I've been going around in circles but I think the way you've just phrased it has added more clarity. So what I need to do is create my own single.html page and look for whatever URL parameters match my content.